# Updating an element's index in an array to zero with a handler function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I want to select an image's index in an array to be set to zero when it is clicked.

For simplicity sake, I have image 1 (index == 0) and image 2 (index == 1). When I click on image 2, the handleImageClick function works by setting image 2's index to zero. The problem is that in order to set image 1's index to zero again, I have to click on image 2 a second time which doesn't make sense. Why is this logical error occuring?

Here is my handleImageClick function :

```
   const handleImageClick = (index) => {
      const newImages = [...images];
      const clickedImage = newImages[index];
      newImages.splice(index, 1);
      newImages.unshift(clickedImage);
      setImages(newImages);
    };
```

Here is how the images are displayed and where onClick is placed:

```
<Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={4} mt={4}>
          {urls.map((url, index) => (
            <Box 
            className="img-container" 
            key={index} 
            position="relative" 
            onClick={() => handleImageClick(index)}
            
            >
              <Image 
                maxHeight="125px" 
                maxW="180px" 
                src={url} 
              />
              <IconButton
                aria-label="Delete"
                icon={<DeleteIcon />}
                onClick={() => handleDeleteImage(index)}
                size="sm"
                colorScheme="red"
                position="absolute"
                top="5px"
                right="5px"
              />
            </Box>
          ))}
        </Grid>
```

urls.map is an array of temporary blob urls that allows the user to see previews of their images.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Using `index` as key in a situation where you are manipulating the array order will only lead to headaches. Use a unique property of each element so that React can accurately track changes in order (and avoid closures over outdated element data).

Answer (score -1):

the `splice()` method extracts the element of the array with the assigned index and it also returns an array with the elements extracted. In this case you only need to extract one element and pass it to the front of the array (**index 0**)

try the following snippet:

```js
let images = [
  {url: "some url", id: ""}, 
  {url: "some url", id: ""}, 
  {url: "some url", id: ""},
  {url: "some url", id: ""}
]

const handleImageClick = (index) => {
  let img = images.splice(index, 1)  
  images = [...img, ...images]
  console.log(images)
}
```

```html
Change the index to zero: 
<button onClick="handleImageClick(0)">img (index 0)</button>
<button onClick="handleImageClick(1)">img (index 1)</button>
<button onClick="handleImageClick(2)">img (index 2)</button>
<button onClick="handleImageClick(3)">img (index 3)</button>
```